# Report to display all top level stories or portlio items in blocked status and include blocked reason

Tags: rally

I would love a report that would display all top level user stories (or better yet portfolio items, if possible) that have one or more tasks in blocked status, with the blocked reasons included in the report. This would be across an entire release

I am thinking that many others would also want to view data like this as well, however I couldn't find this in any of the canned reports. Anyone familiar with a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a custom app that builds a grid of blocked tasks with their workproducts. When a workproduct has a epic (parent) story and a parent feature, those are also shown in respective columns.

The full code is available in [this github repo](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/parents-of-blocked-tasks). You may copy/paste the html file into a custom page in Rally.
The js source:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.TimeboxScopedApp',
    componentCls: 'app',
    scopeType: 'iteration',
    comboboxConfig: {
        labelWidth: 100,
        width: 300
    },
    onScopeChange: function() {

         var filter = this.getContext().getTimeboxScope().getQueryFilter();

        filter = filter.and({
            property: 'Blocked',
            value: true  
        });
        filter.toString();



        Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
            model: 'Task',
            fetch: ['ObjectID', 'FormattedID','Name', 'WorkProduct','Blocked', 'BlockedReason', 'Parent', 'Feature'],
            autoLoad: true,
            filters: [filter],
            listeners: {
                load: this._onDataLoaded,
                scope: this
            }
        }); 

    },
    _onDataLoaded: function(store, data){
                var tasks = [];
                Ext.Array.each(data, function(task) {
                    console.log('Blocked',task.get('Blocked'));
                    console.log(task.get('WorkProduct')._type);
                         var t  = {
                                ObjectID: task.get('ObjectID'),
                                FormattedID: task.get('FormattedID'),
                                Name: task.get('Name'),
                                _ref: task.get('_ref'),
                                WorkProduct: task.get('WorkProduct'),
                                Blocked: task.get('Blocked'),
                                BlockedReason: task.get('BlockedReason'),
                                WorkProductType: task.get('WorkProduct')._type
                            };
                            tasks.push(t);
                }, this);
                this._createGrid(tasks);
    },             

    _createGrid: function(tasks) {
        var that = this;
        var myStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store', {
                data: tasks,
                pageSize: 100,  
            });
        if (!this.grid) {
        this.grid = this.add({
            xtype: 'rallygrid',
            store: myStore,
            columnCfgs: [
                {
                   text: 'Formatted ID', dataIndex: 'FormattedID', xtype: 'templatecolumn',
                    tpl: Ext.create('Rally.ui.renderer.template.FormattedIDTemplate')
                },
                {
                    text: '', dataIndex: 'Name'
                },
                {
                    text: 'WorkProduct', dataIndex: 'WorkProduct',
                    renderer: function(val, meta, record) {
                        var type;
                        if(record.get('WorkProduct')._type === "HierarchicalRequirement") {
                            type = 'userstory';
                        }
                        else if(record.get('WorkProduct')._type === "Defect"){
                            type = 'defect';
                        }
                        return '<a href="https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/detail/' + type + '/' + record.get('WorkProduct').ObjectID + '" target="_blank">' + record.get('WorkProduct').FormattedID + '</a>';
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: 'Blocked Reason', dataIndex: 'BlockedReason'
                },
                 {
                    text: 'Parent of WorkProduct', dataIndex: 'WorkProduct',
                    renderer: function(val, meta, record) {
                        if(record.get('WorkProduct')._type !== "HierarchicalRequirement") {
                            return 'n/a'
                        }
                        else{
                            return '<a href="https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/detail/userstory/' + record.get('WorkProduct').Parent.ObjectID + '" target="_blank">' + record.get('WorkProduct').Parent.FormattedID + '</a>';
                        }

                    }

                },
                 {
                    text: 'Feature of WorkProduct', dataIndex: 'WorkProduct',
                    renderer: function(val, meta, record) {
                        if(record.get('WorkProduct')._type !== "HierarchicalRequirement") {
                            return 'n/a'
                        }
                        else{
                            return '<a href="https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/detail/portfolioitem/feature/' + record.get('WorkProduct').Feature.ObjectID + '" target="_blank">' + record.get('WorkProduct').Feature.FormattedID + '</a>';
                        }

                    }

                }
            ]
        });
         }else{
            this.grid.reconfigure(myStore);
         }
    }
});
```